# Variant of Grönwall's inequality

Tags: inequality

I am wondering if there is a Grönwall-type inequality I can apply for an estimate of the form:
$$u(t) \leq \alpha(t) + \left(\int_a^t |u(s)|^2ds\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}, \; t \in [a,b],$$
where $u: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Thanks

Comment: Could you use Cauchy-Schwarz and then Gronwall? Maybe introduce a helper function?

Comment: Don't really see how C-S is going to help me here, care to elaborate?

Comment: Well, to use Grönwall, you need an inequality of the forum $\displaystyle u(t)\le\alpha(t)+\int_a^t\beta(s)u(s)\,ds,$ for some $\beta$ non-negative. So, what if you were able to dream up a non-negative $\beta$, maybe using C-S, such that $\displaystyle\left(\int_a^t|u(s)|^2\,ds\right)^{1/2}\le\int_a^t\beta(s)u(s)\,ds?$ Wouldn't that get you the conclusion of Grönwall?

Comment: I see, interesting idea. But in order to make this work then $\beta(s)$ will necessarily have to depend on $u(s)$ which is what I am trying to bound?

Comment: Not at all: $\beta$ is something you can dream up, since it's not already present in your problem. Maybe you just try something like $\beta(s)=1$. I don't know if that would work or not - you work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with 
$$ u(t) \leq \alpha(t) + \left(\int_a^t |u(s)|^2ds\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} $$
as given, you can compute
$$ |u(t)|^2 \leq \left[ \alpha(t) + (\int_a^t |u(s)|^2 ds)^\frac12 \right]^2 \leq 2 \alpha(t)^2 + 2 \int_a^t |u(s)|^2 ds $$
where we used the version of AM-GM inequality giving
$$ (a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 \leq 2 (a^2 + b^2). $$

Now you can apply Gronwall's inequality to the function $v(s) = |u(s)|^2$, which gives, for example
$$ |u(t)|^2 \leq 2\alpha(t)^2 + \int_0^t 2\alpha(s)^2 e^{2(t-s)} ds $$
in general, or, if $\alpha$ is non-decreasing and non-negative, then 
$$ |u(t)|^2 \leq 2\alpha(t)^2 e^{2t}. $$

Comment: Awsome! thanks :)

Comment: Can I to conclude analogous things about this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3887005/gronwall-type-inequality-more-generally)?